# How to set CreationDate of downloaded file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-disposition

I have files in an Azure Blob Storage. On a webpage these files can be downloaded.

This works fine but the `creation date` and `modified date` are not set like I need them to.

Here's some code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download()
    {
        Download download;
        [...]
        var fileStorage = new BlobStorage(download.ContainerName);

        BlobProperties blobProperties;
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(fileStorage.Download(download.Url, out blobProperties))
        };

        result.Content.Headers.LastModified = blobProperties.LastModified;

        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = download.FileName,
            CreationDate = blobProperties.LastModified,
            ModificationDate = blobProperties.LastModified,
            Size = blobProperties.Length
        };

        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        return result;
    }
```

`blobProperties.LastModified` has the correct DateTimeOffset value. But when I look at the downloaded file on my disk (running Windows) the date of the file is different. Sometimes it is the current date when downloaded. Sometimes a complete other date which can be sooner or later than the `blobProperties.LastModified`.

When you have a download folder with lots of files this makes it very difficult to find the file.

I need either the current date or the date from the blog properties but not a seemingly random date.

Here's the Fiddler output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 802074
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Tue, 13 Nov 2018 10:17:20 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myFile.xlsx"; creation-date="Tue, 13 Nov 2018 10:17:20 GMT"; modification-date="Tue, 13 Nov 2018 10:17:20 GMT"; size=802074
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?R?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 07 Dec 2018 09:53:17 GMT
```

As you can see the date is set to Nov. 13, the current date is Dec. 7 but the date on my disk is `26-9-2018 16:54`

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Browsers do not implement any Content-Disposition parameters except filename.

Comment: When you download the file, a new file is created, so I don't think you can overwrite that. If you mount your Azure blob as a local storage disk, maybe the creation date will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks @JulianReschke and Isma. I already thought that the browser is creating a new file, but then I would expect the filename be the current date. Sometimes it is but sometimes it is a seemingly random date. That is not something I can control? The current date is fine.